# How to implement Twilio SDK calling in React native?

Tags: react-native, twilio

When i used following command for  Twilio

```
npm install react-native-twilio --save
```

it is install but when run the

```
react-native link react-native-twilio
```

than following error message get

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 
'D:\ReactNative\TwilioApp\TwilioApp\node_modules\rea
ct-native-twilio\package.json'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at getRNPMConfig (D:\ReactNative\TwilioApp\TwilioApp\node_modules\react- 
native\local-cli\core\index.js:52:1)
at Object.getDependencyConfig 
(D:\ReactNative\TwilioApp\TwilioApp\node_modul
es\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:109:18)
at deps.reduce (D:\ReactNative\TwilioApp\TwilioApp\node_modules\react- 
native\local-cli\link\getDependencyConfig.js:18:24)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at getDependencyConfig 
(D:\ReactNative\TwilioApp\TwilioApp\node_modules\reac
t-native\local-cli\link\getDependencyConfig.js:15:15)
at Object.link [as func] 
(D:\ReactNative\TwilioApp\TwilioApp\node_modules\re
act-native\local-cli\link\link.js:151:24) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did the `npm install` command completed successfully or give any warnings/errors? Try running both commands again in an elevated command prompt (using administrator privileges).

Comment: yes i did the npm install command than get npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /sane/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve
nts@1.2.4

Comment: The `react-native-twilio` repo shows that it hasn't received an update in 2 years and that it implements the old Twilio Client SDK and not the new Twilio Programmable Voice SDK. So I would recommend a different module. Try [react-native-twilio-programmable-voice](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice) instead, perhaps?

Comment: So that will work for App to Phone call(Like normal calling) ?

Comment: Thanks that worked for me  react-native-twilio-programmable-voice